# Is there a way to take input from user in vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to get my iterator to the last occurrence of 1.

---

For example, in a vector `A[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]` I want to get my iterator to 6th place in 0 based indexing. I want to do this using vector function but the array won't be hard-coded in the program. The program is to take a vector from user consisting of 0s and 1s and and then get the iterator to last occurrence of 1, thanks!

logically speaking I want to do something like this to get input from user:

```
std::vector<int> b, c;
        for (auto d : b)
            std::cin >> c;
            b.push_back(c);
```

Comment: How is the number of elements determined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to make a vector funtion with parameter of another vector.

like,

```
vector<int>Printvectors(vector<int>vectornew){} // If you want the return type to be 
                                                //            a vector
```

And to accept the value of the users into the vectors what u can do is-

```
vector<int>a;

while(cin>>i){
a.push_back(i);
}

a.sort(a.begin(),a.end()); // to sort
vector<int>Printvectors(vector<int>a);
```

and use the lower bound function i would recommend for the vector to get the iterator at the desired place.use `std::string::find()` to find the element..

Comment: thanks! it worked.. I just needed the "while(cin>>i){
a.push_back(i);
}" part for my vector

Comment: no problem dude this was my first answer glad you found it correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::upper_bound()` to find the index but the array need to be sorted.

Or, you can convert the array to string then use `std::string::find()` to find the element.

Comment: thanks for you response but I can't sort my array and the array will be provided by user.

Answer (score 0):

To read in numbers until there is something that isn't a number, you need to loop testing the result of `>>`

```
std::vector<int> a;
for (int b; std::cin >> b;) { a.push_back(b); }
```

Then you can `std::find` from the end by using `std::reverse_iterator`s

```
auto it = std::find(a.rbegin(), a.rend()).base();
// showing the index
std::cout << std::distance(a.begin(), it);
```

Comment: My question is how can I take values from user in order to fill my vector.

Comment: It works, thanks. Is it possible to do this without throwing in a character at last? like I can give the range like how long the vector is going to be..

Comment: @Lazeeez add a counter, check its not zero, decrease by one.

Answer (score -1):

i suggest you to use something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   array[i]=cin<<"use user input here"
 }
```

for code mistake please apologize me but i no long use c++ since 4 years